# JQueryMobile HTC Android pinch zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, android

I have one website with JQueryMobile which works fine for iPhone but with Android HTC looks really weird when zooming. Same thing happens in any of the demo pages of JQueryMobile site, almost half of the screen becomes blank breaking completely the site.

Is there any way of solving this or at least disable pinch zooming for Android HTC Browsers?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is likely caused by the HTC non-standard android browser. You cannot use the viewport meta tag to prevent pinch zooming. Also the zooming causes the layout to be recalculated (page dimensions are changed) which I assume is what is causing your issues. Unfortunately it doesn't seem like there is a solution for this problem at this time, but it only affects HTC phones.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the viewport metatag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score -2):

Two ways to solve it, either disable jQueryMobile or recode the desired functionality. The goal of jQueryMobile is to provide the same functionality for a variety of mobile browsers, however that statement doesn't include *performance* at all - and most likely never will since the difference between different mobile devices' perfomance is geometrical; that's why you really **can't** have a *write once, run everywhere* type of library for mobile. Unless you degrade your high-end experience to feature phone level, that is. I'm willing to go as far as calling this mentality a fundamental flaw in jQueryMobile.

Also, you should know that Android is generally worse in supporting fancy animations and such than iPhoneOS. Yes, it can do the same things but not as smoothly and there's lots of weird clipping/page position jumping errors and whatnot in the animations.